# Hiding A Facebook App's Presence Completely

Tags: facebook

I need to hide an app's presence in user's profile completely so no one else besides the app's user will be aware of the app. (No notifications will be posted on timeline.) It will be a private app (it's weird to see something like this on a social network eh?) that will only be visible to users of it. Think of it like a personal assistant.

As I've found, the solution is to disable Settings > Advanced > Social Discovery from App settings panel. Will it be enough to address my issue? I'm asking this because there is no good documentation besides the little question mark near the field that makes me paranoid.